# How can I convert blob image from database to html image src

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blob

I have a blob field in the database which stores image blob. I want to convert this to an image in the html image src tag. How can this be done, i am using ASP.NET MVC c# as my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert it to Base64String. First convert it to ByteArray then you can get Base64String.
for example:

```
var imgUrl = $"data:{imageType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(buffer)}";
```